# How access an error response in handler of $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am struggling with accessing an error response (http status and body) in 
Angular $resource handler.

```
MyEntity.load({id: 123}, function (ok) { }, function (a, b, c) {
    console.log("failed " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
})
```

Error callback is invoked with 1 argument. b and c are undefined.
a variable has fields stack and message. Message is a string.

> "[$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received:
>   "Tournament                 41 not found". Parse error: "{}"
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata?   p0=Tournament%2041%20not%20found&p1=%7B%7D"

So I am curious where is the response object. It looks like angularjs fails on json deserialization because my message is not in json.
But bad thing happens. It's not an excuse to fall apart.

```
"angular": "^1.6.4",
"angular-route": "^1.6.4",
"angular-resource": "^1.6.4",
```

Comment: AFAIK, `$resource` only works with JSON and requires your API routes to be RESTful. [Read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource